# Bundle html and css together to send to the server

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, vue.js

I am doing a simple web app, where i am using a external lib called (html-to-pdf). The idea is to create a pdf with the html and css generated on the frontend. The lib receives a html document, so i need to have something like this representation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>cv-maker</title>
  </head>

 <style>
  styles go here
 </style>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

at the moment I am using vue to do the job, since it gives me less headeaches with other stuff. What I need is to convert a component based templated, like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <button @click="sendRequest()"></button>
  </div>
</template>
```

to the above example, so I can extract the component styles and the generated html for the specific component, is there any way to do this?

Currently I am thinking about webpack plugin, but i don't want to build my bundle each time i do a request to the server, is this the good way to do that?

edit: resuming the behaviour i want, basicly i want to extract the html is inside the template witht the class wrapper, and get the styles on the current component and create a single html file with the extracted html from the component and the style embeded on the component with the style tag.

Thanks

Comment: can't you add the css to your HTML using a [`<style>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style) before sending it ?

Comment: ofc i can, but it is still a component based template, i can get the specific html with a id to the root, but then ihow i add the style tag?

Comment: just to be sure I undestood correctly. your div `wrapper` (in the template) have all the HTML(is it valid HTML ?) , css is in an external file.
Maybe you could send an example of what is in your `<template>` before the transformation, that would help me understand better

Comment: i edited the question, basicly i want to extract the html inside the template and create my own index.html file witht that template data and the style on the current component since it is a single file component. that index.html file should be sended to the server where the external library can process it.

Comment: will the html in the template be a full valid html (from `<html>` to `</html>`) or only part of it ?

Comment: also is the lib [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-pdf) ?

Comment: yeah in the external lib it must be a valid html, thats why i need to build it, i can build the html on the server side with the template sent, but how can i send the styles with the style tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178346/discussion-between-jonatjano-and-af-costa).